# Microsoft Cognitive Services Bing WebSearch API v5.0

Tags: php, html, azure

I am having some issues with the new Bing search API from Microsoft Azure (cognitive services). Here is my code below, what I am trying to do is call on the API from my form that I have made and simple show results but I am having some trouble doing so, can someone look at my code and see if there are any issues? The error I keep on getting is that I haven't defined the $q variable but I have as you will see in the code. Thanks for the help, appreciate it!

PHP:

```
<?php
$accountKey = 'account_key';

$url =  'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q='.$q.'&count=10&offset=0&mkt=en-us&safesearch=Moderate';

$q = urlencode($_POST['q']);

$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
  'method'=>"GET",
  'header'=>"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $accountKey"
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$jsonobj = json_decode($file);
echo $file;
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input name="q" type="text" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
<input type="submit" name="Search" hidden>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place `$q = urlencode($_POST['q']);` below `$accountKey`

For example:

```
<?php
 $accountKey = 'account_key';
 $q = urlencode($_POST['q']);
 $url =  'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q='.$q.'&count=10&offset=0&mkt=en-us&safesearch=Moderate';



 $opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $accountKey"
 )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$jsonobj = json_decode($file);
echo $file;
?>
```

You have called the variable before declare.

Comment: the results are just in JSON format is there any guide you would recommend I follow to help style the results a bit? also how would I make it so when I refresh the page it takes me back to the search and doesn't call on the API again?

Comment: Could you please explain little bit, What kind of style need to modify of your Search result?. <?php  if(!isset($_POST['q'])) { // write your code to redirect to search page } ///// Write your code further

Comment: well since it's just plain JSON right now, would there we any way to style the results and make them more like a more conventional search engine like Google?

Comment: Here you can find a Repo for Bing API  in PHP https://github.com/marimuthum17/Bing-API-v5. If you get a result make it in for loop and display how you have needed. If the result count is zero just display like no records found.

Comment: I still am not understanding how I would style results

Answer (score 0):

I have generate a code snippet for you, for your further question:

> also how would I make it so when I refresh the page it takes me back to the search and doesn't call on the API again?
>
> well since it's just plain JSON right now, would there we any way to style the results and make them more like a more conventional search engine like Google?

Please consider following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="get" action="">
<input name="q" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="<?=$_GET['q']?>" autofocus>
<input type="submit" hidden>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
$accountKey = '<accountKey>';
$q = @urlencode($_GET['q']);
if($q){
    $url =  'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q='.$q.'&count=10&offset=0&mkt=en-us&safesearch=Moderate';
    $opts = array(
      'http'=>array(
      'method'=>"GET",
      'header'=>"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $accountKey"
      )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    // Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
    $file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $jsonobj = json_decode($file);
    echo ('<ul ID="resultList">');
    foreach ($jsonobj->webPages->value as $value) {
        echo ('<li class="resultlistitem"><a href="' . $value->url . '">'.$value->name.'</a>');
        if(property_exists($value,'image')){
            echo ('<img src="' . $value->image->contentUrl . '"></li>');
        }
    }
    echo ("</ul>");
    }

?>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer :) however, the URLs are bing URLs. how can I get the links to be the actual URL? so for example if you search "google" or something, the url is not google.com, it's a bing link that redirects to google.com. how can I change this?

Comment: As we are using Bing search API, the results should be the redirect urls. It is by design.

Answer (score 0):

The new cognitive API requires an account key and a subscription key. You will continue to experience errors until both are included.